# popup package not found when installing ac-cider package

Tags: init-file, clojure, cider

When I try to install ac-cider via `package-install` or via `init.el` I get the message http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/popup-20160531.425.el: Not Found:

[image: popup-20160531.425.el: Not Found]

This is the code in my init.el:

```
(require 'package)
;; (add-to-list 'package-archives
;;              '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") t)
;; (add-to-list 'package-archives
;;              '("tromey" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/") t)
;; (add-to-list 'package-archives
;;              '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/")))


;; Load and activate emacs packages. Do this first so that the
;; packages are loaded before you start trying to modify them.
;; This also sets the load path.
(package-initialize)

;; Download the ELPA archive description if needed.
;; This informs Emacs about the latest versions of all packages, and
;; makes them available for download.
(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))

;; The packages you want installed. You can also install these
;; manually with M-x package-install
;; Add in your own as you wish:
(defvar my-packages
  '(ac-cider))
```

How can this be fixed so that ac-cider is installed?

Comment: Do you see any *Messages* about failing to download an archive?

Comment: @JohnKitchin No. Just the message that popup is not found (and therefore fails to download).

Comment: I tried version **0.2.3** from melpa and it installed fine this morning.  Please recheck and try the latest version.  **. . . . Compiling file /Users/HOME/.emacs.d/elpa/popup-0.5.3/popup.el at Wed Jul 20 07:58:46 2016 . . . .**

Comment: @lawlist Thank you. I will do so at home and will let you know the result.

Comment: @lawlist I checked and I still get the error:  `File error: http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/popup-20160531.425.el, Not found`.
`

Comment: It seems that your package archive metadata is corrupted. try deleting .emacs.d/elpa/archives and restart emacs.

Comment: @lurdan Thank you. That sounds like an excellent idea. I will try that later today and let you'll know what the result is.

Comment: @lurdan I tried and I still get the same error. If I pull from melpa-stable though, I get the error: `evil-surround not found`.

Comment: hmm... so, auto-complete which is already installed in your environment may require specific date-versioned popup? How about rename your .emacs.d temporally and re-run with your init.el. I can setup successfully with your init.el pasted above (replacing last defvar with package-install). 'mv .emacs.d .emacs.d-tmp; emacs -Q -l path/to/init.el'

Comment: @lurdan Thanks again. I will try running in a completely clean directory and will let you know the result!

Comment: @lurdan. It works after removing everything but the init.el. Thanks. If you post it as an answer I can give you the bounty if you want ;).

Comment: Good :) I will repost to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your package archive metadata is corrupted.
Try renaming your .emacs.d temporally and re-run with your init.el.

`mv ~/.emacs.d ~/.emacs.d-tmp; emacs -Q -l path/to/init.el`

I can setup successfully with your init.el pasted above (replacing last defvar with package-install).